# The multi-part identifier "tablename.column " could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I used this query above exception has thrown

```
SELECT FINQDET.InquiryNo,FINQDET.Stockcode,FINQDET.BomQty,FINQDET.Quantity,FINQDET.Rate,FINQDET.Required,FINQDET.DeliverTo,FSTCODE.TitleA AS FSTCODE_TitleA ,FSTCODE.TitleB AS FSTCODE_TitleB,FSTCODE.Size AS FSTCODE_Size,FSTCODE.Unit AS FSTCODE_Unit,                                                        FINQSUM.TITLE AS FINQSUM_TITLE,FINQSUM.DATED AS FINQSUM_DATED 

FROM FINQSUM , FINQDET  left outer join [Config]..FSTCODE   ON FINQDET.Stockcode=FSTCODE.Stockcode

WHERE  FINQDET.InquiryNo=FINQSUM.INQUIRYNO   
ORDER BY FINQDET.Stockcode,FINQDET.InquiryNo
```

but if I used below query problem solved,

```
SELECT FINQDET.InquiryNo,FINQDET.Stockcode,FINQDET.BomQty,FINQDET.Quantity,FINQDET.Rate,FINQDET.Required,FINQDET.DeliverTo,FSTCODE.TitleA AS FSTCODE_TitleA ,FSTCODE.TitleB AS FSTCODE_TitleB,FSTCODE.Size AS FSTCODE_Size,FSTCODE.Unit AS FSTCODE_Unit,
FINQSUM.TITLE AS FINQSUM_TITLE,FINQSUM.DATED AS FINQSUM_DATED 

FROM FINQSUM As FINQSUM  , FINQDET  As FINQDET   left outer join [Config]..FSTCODE  As FSTCODE    ON FINQDET.Stockcode=FSTCODE.Stockcode

HERE  FINQDET.InquiryNo=FINQSUM.INQUIRYNO   
ORDER BY FINQDET.Stockcode,FINQDET.InquiryNo
```

Please can you explain Why using Alias better than using actual table names

Comment: What's the text for the exception you're getting?

Comment: In case of SELF JOIN, you have to use ALIAS. Even if you try to use fully qualified name, sql won't be able to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table [Config]..FSTCODE   is qualified with database name which works fine if you use alias. Otherwise you need to qualify full name as it is from different database

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `FSTCODE` is a table in a different DB. In the first query, though the `JOIN` uses the DB name to identify the table, the `ON` statement does not. The second statement adresses this by using an `ALIAS`

You can also modify the first statement as

```
left outer join [Config]..FSTCODE   
ON FINQDET.Stockcode=[Config]..FSTCODE.Stockcode
```

Answer (score 0):

An alias allows you to reference a set without using the fullname. It saves you typing and allows you to express contextual information to the reader.